# Loading order of assets stack: how is it managed by browser?

Tags: performance

I have an issue, which i can't explain me - i seem to miss some basics. Could somebody explain me in plain words the browser behavior, which i describe further?

Given is a html document with some javascripts implemented on the bottom, according to performance best practices (but not async and/or defer). All fine, browser reads html file from top to bottom without to be blocked, reads all resources and forms the loading stack (all assets, images, javascripts, fonts, ...).

Then i realize in the timeline of dev. tools: the stack is ordered in that order, as assets are appearing in the html file:

- firstly some images from CSS file, which is in the head,
- then some images from the middle of the body,
- then javascripts on very bottom, like they are implemented in the html file, and as i expect to see them.

But in the network diagram, if i sort it on download start time, i realize, that javascripts are loaded at the very first, before everything.

This is, what i don't understand and where i need an explanation: why the network diagram shows me a loading order, which differs from the implementing and timeline order?

On attached images is the loading order in timeline and waterfall visible:
[image: waterfall]
[image: timeline]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered on stackoverflow.

> If you aren't dynamically loading scripts or marking them as defer or
>   async, then scripts are loaded in the order encountered in the page.
>   It doesn't matter whether it's an external script or an inline script
>   - they are executed in the order they are encountered in the page. Inline scripts that come after external scripts have are held until
>   all external scripts that came before them have loaded and run.

Full answer can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996852/load-and-execute-order-of-scripts/8996894#8996894

Comment: Hmm, interesting thread, thanks. But i just wonder about opposite behavior, as shown on waterfall diagram: javascripts are implemented on the bottom without `defer / async`, but in waterfall are displayed, as they would be loaded first of all, just after html and js+css from the head...

Comment: If I am seeing it correctly it looks like you do in fact have a js in the <head> you want to place all your js just before the </body> . CSS will only be downloaded when the selector is rendered, which will be after the scripts are loaded in the <head>. It looks like there is 1 js in the head that is blocking the loading of your CSS.

Comment: i have one js and one css in the head - they are necessary to be loaded firstly. But all other js i implement before closing </body>, absolutely as you said. It makes me open-mouthed, why js from the html's end are shown in the waterfall at first

Comment: Are all your JS external? I can not see in your pic.